# How to show chat head facebook android manually?

Tags: facebook, chat

The new version of Facebook Messenger show a chat head when new messages arrived.

When closed, I don't know how to show the chat head unless waiting for the next message to come

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you want a permanent notification icon so that you can just open the chat app from your notification bar? Or are you asking for something else?

Comment: An icon or shortcut to open the chat head is what I look for

Comment: I use Messenger, and yes, chat heads do show, what I do is, type in to chat, then back out and finish, it is up to them to reply back, and when they do, their chat head re-appears with a new message, in short, that would be the behaviour of Messenger itself, doubt if you can force the chat head to be on permanently all the time...

Comment: @t0mm13b Why would you doubt that :) ? I just want to positively chat to my friend using the chat head and need to open it! I like to chat with being-float app like that without living my current app

Answer (score 1):

A free app called [Notification Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.nicolai.buch.andersen.ns&hl=en) gives you the ability to set up a permanent notification that will open an app you specify when you select the notification.

You can set up multiple shortcuts and can even set up toggles for wifi, bluetooth, etc, if you want.

The downside to this is that when you receive a message, you'll have a *second* notification from the chat app itself. But since the facebook chat app lacks an option to set up a permanent notification, this 3rd-party app is the next best solution.

Comment: They have updated their Facebook app now. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the new update to [Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en) app now, the chat head is opened whenever I start my chat with a friend.

Note that if we want to use the old way of chatting via Facebook, we would use the [Facebook Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca&hl=en) app.

Answer (score 1):

Open messenger then click on the chat head you wanna open. Click i for info. Click 3 dot on the upper right corner then click "open chat head".

Answer (score 0):

Open messenger then click on the chat head you wanna create shortcut for. Click i for info. Click 3 dot on the upper right corner then click "Create shortcut". This will create shortcut on your home screen, that will open chathead for this conversation.